# Xcode 7 : Autolayout to UICollectionViewCell that are generated programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uicollectionviewcell, nslayoutconstraint

I've an **CollectionView that generates nine collectionview cell at run-time** (set it programmatically).

There is only one CollectionView Cell in Storyboard.

I've question that **how to set constraint to Cell such that it appears as shown in screenshot.**

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

since your layout showing that there will be 3 cells per row. you need to divide your collection view width with 3 plus space for separators. one good way is to attached collection view left right top bottom with autolayout. and use dummy cell with label as a center. you need to work programmatically on this delegate.

```
 - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat screenWidth = collectionViewFrame.size.width;
    float cellWidth = screenWidth / 3.0 - 20; //Replace the divisor with the column count requirement. Make sure to have it in float.
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellWidth);

    return size;
}
```

Comment: What would be equivalent version in Swift? I'm not able to locate it.

Comment: This is swift equivalent version.

func collectionView(collectionView : UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout:UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> CGSize

Answer (score 0):

For collection view you can set distance between lines and cell from storyboard.
**initially you need to set minimum spacing for line and cell.**

[image]

Then you need to set dynamic width for cell based on width of device, 
and make sure to deduct 2*minimum spacing from that width.and also deduct section insets if there is any for left or right.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
return CGSizeMake((Device_Width/3.0)-2*(Minimum cell spacing+section_insets.left), 120.0)

//for iphone 4 in my case
```

// return CGSizeMake((320/3.0)-(2*1)-2(10),100.0)
     }

Device width is width of device.
minimum cell spacing which you have set in storyboard
section_inset.left which is also as per storyboard value.

Comment: I'm already getting that result but I want this with autolayout.

Comment: you may need to set a label(1 - 9 ) and Image (X)
you can set constraint of both as **center horizontal and center vertical** .
So if cell width will be increased by code then also that both will be in center.